# How to fetch the com port or any id I can use to upload specific program to a specific arduino? e.g. "a.ino" to arduino micro

Tags: arduino-micro, arduino-pro-micro

My project is a head mouse for which I am using two arduino boards . I want to upload a specific program to a specific arduino. How can I do it? And if I need to use a pid or com port id about which the official arduino forum people suggested, how can I retrieve this id? I'm using an Arduino micro and a pro micro if it helps any.

I need some suggestion on how to load the sketch to arduino through code without actually opening the arduino ide directly.Because it's a client project. And how can I make a specific program upload to the specific arduino one at a time. e.g. "a.ino" to arduino micro and "b.ino" to arduino pro micro. How should I identify the arduino boards through code.As for the OS, I am using Windows 10 64 bit.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I am using windows @majekno. And yes, I need some suggestion on how to load the sketch to arduino through code without actually opening the arduino ide directly.Because it's a client project. And how can I make a specific program upload to the specific arduino one at a time. e.g. "a.ino" to arduino micro and "b.ino" to arduino pro micro. Hpw should I identify the arduino boards through code.

Comment: done @jsotola. Please, help me solve it.